# jsp getAttribute return null

Tags: jsp

i have the problems where when i get the attriubute , it contains null, but the variable i assign to it gets the value

heres is the perviouse page how i pass location:

```
<%if(rs.next()) {%>
<td><a href="university.jsp?location=<%=rs.getInt("cs_id")%>"><%out.print((String)  (rs.getString("country_state")));%></a></td>
<%}else{ break; } %>
```

here is the page not getting the parameter
    Please select your University State or Enter your University:

```
<%
    //set the session the each parameter
    String locationString = request.getParameter("location");

    Integer locationId = Integer.valueOf(locationString);

    session.setAttribute("locationId",locationString);

    System.out.print(locationString);
    System.out.print(request.getAttribute("locationId"));
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `session.setAttribute("locationId", locationString);` to put attribute to `session`
but you try to get attribute from `request` via`request.getAttribute("locationId")`

`request.getAttribute` is different from `session.getAttribute`